# MATLAB how do I get data from a csv in Matlab on Linux? xlsread and importdata

Tags: matlab, csv, xlsread, importdata

I have a script that analyzes data from a csv using `xlsread` but I need to run the script on Linux, and I am currently using Windows10, so `xlsread` does not work. I have tried to use the 'basic' parameter, but that does not work.

```
data = xlsread("set1.csv"); % this extracts data that are integers or binary (TRUE/FALSE)
[~, data_id] = xlsread("set1.csv","A2:A10"); % this extracts the first column, which has subject IDs which are strings
```

I have tried to use `importdata` which gives me a structure with `data` and `textdata`, but **(a)** I do not know why `data` has only 2 columns (of numeric type) even though there are many more and **(b)** textdata has all column data as strings, but the headers from my original csv do not match the columns within textdata: The headers are all applied to the first column, so the first column has all the headers, separated by commas, and the other columns do not have headers.

I want to be able to grab the data from my csv using something comparable to `xlsread` that works in Linux. I have looked around with `readtable`, `readmatrix`, `readcell`, `importdata`, but I have not found anything that gives me exactly what I want, since the data within my .csv are mixed type: strings, integers, binary.

Answer (score 0):

[Use the import tool](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importtool.html) on the toolstrip. You can then generate the code that was run to import the data you selected.

Comment: I am running the script on a cluster, so I will not have access to matlab ondemand web portal every time I want to run the script. Any advice for this?

Comment: Just do it once, then copy the generated code